# How to update an array of objects in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array of objects to save comments. I want to find a correct `postid` and insert a new object to that array whenever a user leaves a comment.

**Schema**

```
"comments" : {
  "-KfXyMUIqsiPGElax098" : {
     "comments" : [ {
       "author" : "s123456",
       "comment" : "This is the first comment."
      } ],
     "postid" : "-KfSToVpsWUecTL_tmlh"
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class CommentNew {

String author;
String comment;

public CommentNew() {}

public CommentNew(String author, String comment) {
    this.author = author;
    this.comment = comment;}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;}
}
```

**Code**

I find the correct `postid`, but how can I append a new object to the array?

```
    public void saveComment(String postIdKey, final CommentNew commentNew) {
    Query queryRef = mFirebase.child("comments").orderByChild("postid").equalTo(postIdKey);
    queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = snapshot.getKey();
                String path = "comments/" + key + "/comments";
                List comment = new ArrayList<CommentNew>(Arrays.asList(commentNew));
                Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                result.put("comments", commentNew);
                mFirebase.child(path).updateChildren(result);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post your `CommentNew` class definiton.

Comment: @RamithDR I post `CommentNew` class.

Comment: Thanks for posting the class. Try the solution included in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The path you're on is correct to update data, but you're missing few steps.

**Step 1:**

Your `CommentNew` class should contain a method to convert a `CommentNew` object to a HashMap. like this:

```
public class CommentNew {

String author;
String comment;

public CommentNew() {}

public CommentNew(String author, String comment) {
    this.author = author;
    this.comment = comment;}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;}

//converts an object of CommentNew to a HashMap
@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {

   HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
   result.put("author", getAuthor());
   result.put("comment", getComment());

   return result;
}

}
```

**Step 2:**

Change the code in `onDataChange`to the following:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

       String key = snapshot.getKey();       
       String path = "comments/" + key + "/comments";

       Map<String, Object> updatedComment = commentNew.toMap();
       Map<String, Object> childUpdate = new HashMap<>();
       childUpdate.put(path, updatedComment);

       mFirebase.updateChildren(childUpdate);
   }
}
```

As you can see two HashMaps were used, the first HashMap is used to store your updated attributes list of `CommentNew` object, and the second HashMap contains the path the child should update + the updated data.

Optionally you can add an `OnCompleteListener` to the `updateChildren` method and give Toast to the user that the comment was updated successfully or anything you prefer.

Additional read : [Update specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

HTH, comment below if you need any further clarifications;

Comment: This doesn't work. Because  `CommentNew` Model is stored as an array. Take a look at http://i.imgur.com/mQyv91j.png .Also, the old data is replaced by new data.

Comment: It seems saving comment as an array is not a good idea. Probably, I should change the structure

Comment: @David That's true, nested data like that is harder to maintain. If you could update the question with your project scenario I might be able to help you out with the database structure.